# 'Deleted By' missing in mobile site

Tags: bug, deleted-answers, mobile

The screenshot below is from within Safari on iOS 6.1.3. The "Deleted by" text is missing from the post. The post is shaded differently, but it is not immediately obvious (to me, at least) that it is because the post was deleted.

[image: iOS screenshot]

And the screenshot below is from FF 19.0.2 on WinXP

[image: FF screenshot]

Comment: Well, that was easy to reproduce. :)